# Slow MySQL query with Group by

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by

I have a query that is taking a long time to execute minutes and more. The two tables orders and tickets have around 150k records. This is the query:

```
SELECT 
  orders.id,
  count(distinct tickets.id) as attached_tickets 
from
  orders
  LEFT JOIN tickets ON tickets.order_id = orders.id
GROUP BY
  orders.id  
LIMIT 1;
```

I have found that by removing the ORDER BY statement it speeds it up to seconds. These are the results from the EXPLAIN

```
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | orders  | NULL       | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 121291 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tickets | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |   7347 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

And yes i have indexes in both tables by id. Is there any way I can speed up my query?

Comment: Try to use "Where" Clause in the Query.

Comment: Your query has to count  everything to just throw away all but the first row. Add a condition to select only rows for the minimal orders.id and remove the limit.

Comment: And you seem to be missing an index on order_id in tickets. That might make the query faster 100-1000 times by itself.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE orders\G; (and for tickets).

Comment: What is the relationship between orders and tickets?  There seem to be a lot more orders than tickets, yet you are counting the number of tickets for one order???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be a lot faster, but has flaws:

```
SELECT  id, 
      ( SELECT  count(*)
            FROM  tickets
            WHERE  order_id = o.id 
      ) as attached_tickets
    FROM  orders AS o
    LIMIT  1;
```

It will need `INDEX(order_id)` on `tickets`.

- Which order.id do you want?  There is no `ORDER BY` to say which one `LIMIT 1` will pick.
- This may not generalize well.  What is your *real* query?